# Hiding Firefox F12 developer tools panel (Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, automation, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium WebDriver to automate my test cases and one of it consists in resizing the screen to a certain dimension and checking if a scrollbar is displayed (in order to validate the responsiveness of the website). The test works pretty well, but many times, when Firefox opens, the "F12 panel" is displayed, so the screen is more narrow and the scrollbar is displayed.

I do have a trick (if a scrollbar is displayed, I create a Robot instance which presses F12 button) but it's not always working, so I'm looking for a cleaner solution to hide the F12 panel.

NOTE : I know that when I open Firefox manually and close the F12 panel, then the next time I open it, it will be hidden. But this is not always true when I launch a parallelized test suite.

Thanks in advance if you have an idea

Comment: Have you searched for any option to disable all extensions, or to start the browser without extensions?

Comment: Unfortunately the F12 panel isn't an extension so I'm not able to dismiss it...

Comment: You would need to try some things to reproduce this in order to find a solution.Each time a test is executed it should start a browser with clean session/cookies/cache and this type of issues should not be present.